# What is the proper workflow for being able to update code within a Git Submodule?

Tags: git, git-submodules

I'm trying to implement a shared library as a Git submodule and I'm struggling with the best practice for pushing changes within the submodule folder. I can get it to work but it feels awkward.

This is my test repo https://github.com/rupe120/submodule-test

I setup the submodules to track a given branch but that doesn't help after a fresh clone and submodule update. I understand that the sub module reference is a gitlink but when I go into the submodule I am unable to push because the "branch" it references is not a branch but seemingly the gitlink.

I either need to checkout the tracked branch in the submodule, so I can push the changes and pull down them down in a separate clone (performing a `git pull` and `git submodule update`). The problem is that any time I want to make a change a file in the submodule folder after performing a submodule update, I need to first checkout the tracked branch to get it off of the gitlink or push using `git push origin HEAD:<name-of-tracked-branch>`

It seems that I should not need to specify the name of the tracked branch in my push when its already part of the configuration. Is there something I'm missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A [`git clone --recurse-submodules`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-clone#Documentation/git-clone.txt---recurse-submodulesltpathspecgt) should clone, checkout and update both submodule to their latest commits of their respective remote trakcing branches.

But they would still be checked out at a SHA1, not in a branch.

You would need a [foreach command to check their branch](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18799234/6309):

```
git submodule foreach -q --recursive 'git switch $(git config -f $toplevel/.gitmodules submodule.$name.branch || echo main)'
```

multiple lines:

```
git submodule foreach -q --recursive \
  'git switch \
  $(git config -f $toplevel/.gitmodules submodule.$name.branch || echo main)'
```

The [OP Josh Russo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/401173/josh-russo) points out [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69488112/what-is-the-proper-workflow-for-being-able-to-update-code-within-a-git-submodule/69491782#comment122832557_69491782) to [this gist](https://gist.github.com/rupe120/92200f38b92dd85721378b9a03707f77):

```sh
git pull
git submodule update --init --remote
git submodule foreach  -q --recursive 'git switch $(git config -f $toplevel/.gitmodules submodule $name.branch || echo main)'
git submodule foreach  -q --recursive 'git pull'
```

Comment: Ok, so what I really want seems to be something like this https://gist.github.com/rupe120/92200f38b92dd85721378b9a03707f77

Comment: @JoshRusso Yes, that should work. I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.

Comment: the paste of the code seems to have added some stray spaces that will cause it to fail on the last line between the hyphens and the switches

Comment: @JoshRusso Thank you. I have edited the answer (as I could: I am on my phone)